# Html, CSS and BOOTSTRAP editor for colleagues who can't code

Tags: html, css, editor, bootstrap

I have redisgned a companie's intranet site which was designed on HTML 4 with the layout being based on table rows.

I have seperate files for the HTML, CSS and the layout(bootstrap). I am unable to find a free editor that can alter the bootsrap and the HTML at the same time.

I need the editor to be able to do the following

Edit Text
revise Hyperlinks
insert new rows
add hyperlinks
Edit non-link text

Is there a software that can accomplish this by uploading the source files ?